# Changing satellite resources assembly while WPF application is running

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

Looking at [WPF Globalization and Localization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx) it looks like WPF reads Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and selects the resources assembly.

Is it possible to load an assembly in code and have the UI use the new localized data?  Something like an "English" button to load en-US and a "Spanish" button to load "es-MX"?

Answer (score 1):

You'd likely have to close and reopen any windows for the change to take effect.  See this thread:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4f19508a-923e-4f48-8142-fc192e1d28ff